# Xamarin Android: How to get an abtract list value in the recyclerview

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I've implemented a recyclerview and separated rows by group. I'm using an abstract list to separate rows.

I inserted a checkbox on the toolbar to select all the rows in recyclerview and its working, but I also wish to do is use a list to store a column value and here where is showing an error, because the value i want to store is inserted in the list that feed the recyclerview rows.

my recyclerview adapter:

```
public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private List<ListItem> mEmails;
    private Activity mActivity;
    public static int listPosition;
    private int position_collectID = 0;
    private List<collectSubject> mcollecSubject;

    private Boolean isSelected = false;

    public Boolean IsSelected()
    {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Boolean selected)
    {

        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public RecyclerAdapter(List<ListItem> emails, Activity activity)
    {
        mEmails = emails;
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return mEmails[position].getType();
    }

    public override int ItemCount => mEmails.Count;

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        if (viewType == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER_DATENOW)
        {
            View headNow = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.recyclerviewNow, parent, false);

            RecyclerViewNowHolder view = new RecyclerViewNowHolder(headNow);
            return view;
        }

        else if (viewType == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER_DATEYESTERDAY)
        {
            View headYesterday = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.recyclerviewYesterday, parent, false);

            RecyclerViewYesterdayHolder view = new RecyclerViewYesterdayHolder(headYesterday);
            return view;
        }

        else if (viewType == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER_BEFORE)
        {
            View headBefore = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.recyclerviewBefore, parent, false);

            RecyclerViewBeforeHolder view = new RecyclerViewBeforeHolder(headBefore);
            return view;
        }

        else
        {
            View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
            RecyclerViewHolder view = new RecyclerViewHolder(row);
            return view;
        }


    }
    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        int type = GetItemViewType(position);
        if (type == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER_DATENOW)
        {
            RecyclerViewNowHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewNowHolder;
            myHolder.mDateNow.Text = "Hoje";

        }

        else if (type == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER_BEFORE)
        {
            RecyclerViewBeforeHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewBeforeHolder;
            myHolder.mDateBefore.Text = "Antes";

        }

        else if (type == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER_DATEYESTERDAY)
        {
            RecyclerViewYesterdayHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewYesterdayHolder;
            myHolder.mDateYesterday.Text = "Ontem";

        }

        else
        {
            RecyclerViewHolder myHolder = holder as RecyclerViewHolder;

            myHolder.mDate.Text = ((Email)mEmails[position]).date;
            myHolder.mSubject.Text = ((Email)mEmails[position]).Subject;
            myHolder.mMessage.Text = ((Email)mEmails[position]).Message;

            myHolder.ItemView.SetBackgroundColor(((ListItem)mEmails[position]).IsSelected() ? Color.LightBlue : Color.Transparent);
            myHolder.ItemView.Tag = position;

        }
    }

    public void checkall()
    {

        int itemcheck = 0;
        if (mEmails != null)
        {
            mcollecSubject = new List<collectSubject>();

            foreach (ListItem email in mEmails)
            {

                email.setSelected(true);

                if (mcollecSubject == null) ;

                mcollecSubject.Add(new collectSubject() { Subject = ((Email)mEmails[itemcheck]).Subject });

                itemcheck++;

            }
        }

    }

}
```

where i calling the recyclerview:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    public static RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    public static RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder;
    public RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<ListItem> mItems;
    public static List<Email> mEmails;
    public static Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    public static Android.Widget.CheckBox checkbox;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerViwer);
        mRecyclerView.AddItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.Context, DividerItemDecoration.Vertical));
        mRecyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;
        SetupList();

        List<string> dateList = new List<string>();
        List<DateNow> dateNow = new List<DateNow>();
        List<DateYesterday> dateYesterday = new List<DateYesterday>();
        List<DateBefore> dateBefore = new List<DateBefore>();

        mItems = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (var email in mEmails)
        {
            if (!dateList.Contains(email.date))
            {
                dateList.Add(email.date);
                dateNow.Add(new DateNow() { dateNow = email.date });
                dateYesterday.Add(new DateYesterday() { dateYesterday = email.date });
                dateBefore.Add(new DateBefore() { dateBefore = email.date });
            }

        }

        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        string sub = today.ToString().Substring(0, 10);

        int yesterday = Convert.ToInt32(today.Day.ToString()) - 1;
        string ontem = today.Month.ToString() + "/" + yesterday.ToString() + "/" + today.Year.ToString();
        string ontem2 = today.Month.ToString() + "/" + yesterday.ToString() + "/" + "201";

        foreach (var date in dateNow)
        {
            string currentmes = today.Month.ToString();
            if (date.dateNow.Equals(sub))
            {
                mItems.Add(date);
                foreach (var email in mEmails)
                {
                    if (email.date.Equals(sub))
                    {
                        mItems.Add(email);

                    }

                }
            }

            else if (date.dateNow.Equals(ontem))
            {
                foreach (var DateYesterday in dateYesterday)
                {
                    if (DateYesterday.dateYesterday.Equals(ontem))
                    {
                        mItems.Add(DateYesterday);
                        foreach (var email in mEmails)
                        {
                            if (email.date.Equals(ontem))
                            {
                                mItems.Add(email);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        int count = 0;
        foreach (var DateBefore in dateBefore)
        {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                mItems.Add(DateBefore);
                foreach (var email in mEmails)
                {
                    if (!email.date.Equals(ontem) && !email.date.Equals(sub))
                    {
                        mItems.Add(email);
                    }

                }

            }

            count = 1;
        }

        //Create our layout Manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(mItems, this);
        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

        var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        CheckBox checkbox = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox);
        checkbox.Click += (o, e) => {
            if (checkbox.Checked)
            {
                mAdapter.checkall();
            }
        };
    }

    private void SetupList()
    {
        mEmails = new List<Email>();
        mEmails.Add(new Email() { date = "9/25/2019", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
        mEmails.Add(new Email() { date = "9/25/2019", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
        mEmails.Add(new Email() { date = "9/25/2019", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
        mEmails.Add(new Email() { date = "9/24/2019", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
        mEmails.Add(new Email() { date = "9/24/2019", Subject = "Wanna Hang Out?", Message = "I ' ll   be around  tomorrow!!" });
    }
```

the error is on line in the recyclerview:

```
     mcollecSubject.Add(new collectSubject() { Subject = ((Email)mEmails[itemcheck]).Subject });
```

the error is:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code,we can see there are several subclasses of `ListItem`.

```
   if (viewType == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER_DATENOW)
    {// Corresponding subclass: DateNow.cs
        View headNow = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.recyclerviewNow, parent, false);

        RecyclerViewNowHolder view = new RecyclerViewNowHolder(headNow);
        return view;
    }

    else if (viewType == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER_DATEYESTERDAY)
    {// Corresponding subclass: DateYesterday.cs
        View headYesterday = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.recyclerviewYesterday, parent, false);

        RecyclerViewYesterdayHolder view = new RecyclerViewYesterdayHolder(headYesterday);
        return view;
    }

    else if (viewType == ListItem.TYPE_HEADER_BEFORE)
    {// Corresponding subclass: DateBefore.cs
        View headBefore = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.recyclerviewBefore, parent, false);

        RecyclerViewBeforeHolder view = new RecyclerViewBeforeHolder(headBefore);
        return view;
    }
    else
    {//The left is subclass Email.cs
        View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.row, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewHolder view = new RecyclerViewHolder(row);
        return view;
    }
```

Since the class `Email` is the child class of `ListItem`, so you can cast `ListItem` to `Email`, but you need to determine which subclass the current class corresponds to.(`DateNow.cs`, `DateYesterday.cs`,  `DateBefore.cs` and `Email.cs` )

For example:

```
            ListItem item = mEmails[itemcheck];
            if (item is Email)
            {
                Email email = (Email)mEmails[itemcheck];
                string subject = email.Subject;
            }
            else if (item is DateNow)
            {
                DateNow date = (DateNow)mEmails[itemcheck];

            }
            else if (item is DateBefore)
            {
                DateBefore date = (DateBefore)mEmails[itemcheck];

            }
            else 
            {// the left is DateYesterday
                DateYesterday date = (DateYesterday)mEmails[itemcheck];

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error states:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

From the line:

```cs
Subject = ((Email)mEmails[itemcheck]).Subject
```

Here you are trying to cast `mEmails[itemcheck]` to type `Email`.  However you have declared your mEmails list as:

```cs
private List<ListItem> mEmails;
```

So you have a list of `ListItem` objects, not a list of `Email` objects.  This is an invalid cast because you can't cast a `ListItem` object into an `Email` object.